# DEBUG trap storing unexpanded variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to capture the commands run in my script so they can be repeated by a logger. One of my functions executes commands stored in an array. When it does this, my DEBUG trap to store the commands in another array stores the unexpanded variable instead of the command that was run.

Here is an example:

```
set -o functrace
queue=("echo stuff" "echo things")
commands=()
lastcmd () { echo "Last command: ${commands[-4]}" ; }
runqueue () {
    until [[ "${#queue[@]}" == 0 ]] ; do
        ${queue[-1]}
        lastcmd
        unset "queue[-1]"
     done
}
trap 'commands+=("$BASH_COMMAND")' DEBUG
runqueue
```

Which results in the following output:

```
bash-4.4$ runqueue
things
Last command: ${queue[-1]}
stuff
Last command: ${queue[-1]}
```

Is there any way to record the commands post-expansion?

Comment: Seems an XY problem, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard options to log debug information are :

- `set -v` : to show command before expansion
- `set -x` : to show command after expansion

in your particular case `eval echo "Last command: ${commands[-4]}" ;` will evaluate

```
eval echo "Last command: ${commands[-4]}"
# after expansion
eval echo "Last command: ${queue[-1]}"
# after eval
echo Last command: echo thing
```

Or easier, directly

```
lastcmd () { echo "Last command: ${queue[-1]}" ; }
```

Comment: I had tried variations of using eval to no avail in my main script, but your usage here does make the example code work. From that, I tried putting eval in a subshell, which worked to my surprise. You can see what I'm using this for here: https://github.com/MrDrMcCoy/bblib/blob/5a008ae1949743a014cd4d1f8ec82434821df63e/bblib.bash#L114

Comment: note that `eval` should be avoided or used when understanding what it actually does and may break on command that contains special characters like `*` or even execute command